# Is there a general or collective term for a gathering that involves eating?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

For example lunch, dinner, birthday part or food at a wake as opposed to a gathering not may or may not serve food and drink.

Answer (score 2):

There a plenty of nouns and compound nouns for this:

> - **dinner party - noun:** a social occasion at which guests eat dinner together.
> - **soirée - noun:** an evening party or gathering, typically in a private house, for conversation or music.
> - **banquet - noun:** an elaborate and formal evening meal for many people.
>     "a state banquet at Buckingham Palace"

Also give this a shot:
http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/soiree?s=t

Answer (score 0):

Not as such, no.

As Mr Griggs linked, there are numerous words for *specific kinds* of such gatherings: a feast or banquet will be a large communal meal, a ball will involve ballroom dancing, an orgy will... well, you can go look that one up yourself.

There's nothing in common use that precisely that means "any gathering with food as opposed to those without". We usually just call them meals in daily life and "X with food and drink" for events like wakes where people might not expect food to be present.

Answer (score 0):

Why not *[repast](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/repast)*

> something taken as food :  meal

*Merriam-Webster*

While it is more often used to refer to a full meal, it can be used to describe lighter fare.

> a meal or the food provided at a meal: *a light repast*

*[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/repast)*